# Get/create Polygon with Google Maps Web Service API

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

I need to access an existing map with a polygon or create a new polygon with given coordinates through Google Maps Web Service.

I'm building a  java application that needs to access a polygon and check if some given coordinates are inside a drawn polygon (coordinates loaded from KML or sent though parameters).

All this needs to be done on runtime so I don't need to display a map, I only need to access the map and check the polygon with the coordinates.

I've tried the javascript API but it's of little use given that my application wont be able to call javascript functions on runtime.

Any ideas where I might start?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the use case is here. If you're not creating a map, you don't need the Maps API. There are well known point-in-polygon algorithms you can search on. You might also look into the [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html), which has that function built in.

If you do want to create a map, same recommendation applies. You can use the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to display the point and the polygon without using JavaScript.